# Cannot post to a server in express

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have an express app that takes basic user input data. All of my get routes work fine but when submit a post request to the server I get a 404 on the url I'm posting to even though I have this page in my views folder.

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var consolidate = require('consolidate');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var database = require('./database/database');
var Patient = require('./models/models').Patient;
var morgan = require('morgan');
var routes = require('./routes');
var app = express();

app.engine('html', consolidate.nunjucks);

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', './views');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
//app.use(app.router);
app.use(routes);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.listen(3055);

module.exports = app;
```

routes/index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Patient = require('../models/models').Patient;
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('index.html');
});

router.post('/addsubject', function(req, res, next){
    Patient.create(req.body).then(function(patient){
        res.redirect('/profile');
    }).catch(function(err){
        if(error.name === "SequelizeValidationError"){
       } else {
       return next(err);
       }
   }).catch(function(error){
      res.send(500, error);
   });
});

router.get('/profile', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('./profile.html');
});

router.get('/addsubject', function(req, res, next){
    // .... do something here ..
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have the `<form action="/addsubject" method="post">` in my index.html file.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>dabl Demographic</title>
  <body>
    <h2>Add Subject</h2>
      <form action="/addsubject" method="post">
        <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
        <br>
        <label for="sname">Second Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname">
        <br>
        <label for="dob">dob: </label>
        <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob">
        <br>
        <label for="laterality">Laterality: </label>
        <input type="text" name="laterality" id="laterality">
        <br>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can share your full index.html or form content ?

Comment: Yes, one second I'll update

Comment: Are you sure `router.post` takes an error as the first callback param ?

Comment: That was a mistake .. I took it out still getting a 404

Comment: The post middleware worked when I had it as app.post() but I decided to break the project down using router .. after this everytime I tried to submit user input through the form I got a 404 everytime ..

Comment: Side note, don't hesitate to mention people (with the @) when you reply to a comment, this way they get notified. [see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass wrong function (error handling function) to the POST route.

Just remove first "err" param from the function like this:

```
router.post('/addsubject', function(req, res, next){
```

Comment: Done still getting a 404

Comment: If you debug app and put brake point to the first line of the controller (line starting "Patient.create"), do you get to that brake point when touch the route?

I see another possible problem, that you do not do nothing after catching the "SequelizeValidationError". You should pass next(err) with some Error object instance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `body-parser` middleware before `app.router`

```
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(morgan('dev'));
//app.use(app.router);
app.use(routes);
...
```

Comment: I forgot to say, btw remove err from `router.post('/addsubject', function (err, req, res, next)..`

Comment: @Donal5  I can run your code in my env and can get form data in `router.post('/addsubject'.. `middleware, I think problem is in your `Patient.create(req.body)` section. probably you need to check `err` details

Comment: Thanks @agit I found the error.. I added next(err); under the if(error.name === "SequelizeValidationError"); Problem solved

Comment: Accepted answer because of @agit comment about next(err); above ^

Comment: @Donal5 I feel a bit aggrieved about your decidion to accept this answer, instead of my answer, which was direct solution to your problem including the comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
}).catch(function(err){
        if(error.name === "SequelizeValidationError"){
          next(err); //next(err); called inide this block no more 404 error
       }
```

User input is now succesfully passed through the body-parser.